# Custom sort in excel , by each account name and then by cost

Tags: excel

I have an excel like

I want to sort the value by the Second column but[image]
I want to retain the "yellow" colored rows containing total values as well after each sorting group, so the expected output will be BARBIE MEDICO first then the total sum of BARBIE, then RAJESH ..

When I tried Sort Box with Name and Then BY, all cost ( yellow) rows are coming on the top

Another example
[image]

Comment: You could add a formula to the blank yellow lines `= ValueAbove & 1`.  So _Barbie Medico_ would contain _Barbie Medico1_ and _Barbie Medico11_ .  Colour so it's same colour as background.  Should sort correctly then.

Comment: Actually yellow lines are already containing the total sum, added a new image for clarification

Comment: Only the last column has the totals.  You're trying to sort by the second column (first column in your second picture).  Add the formula to the second column as that's the one you're sorting on.